# Fitnesse - Getting the absolute path for a fitnesse url

Tags: .net, fitnesse

I am busy learning fitnesse at the moment and have not been able to figure out how to work out how to get an absolute path from a relative url.
I want to be able to upload test files to the files directory on a fitnesse server and then read those files in my test fixture.
e.g.

```
public void ReadTextFileContent(string fileName)
{
   Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
}
```

Note: The fileName would be the fully qualified path to the file.  I want to be able to define this path in terms of the relative path to the fitnesse server so that in a multi user setup, users will not need to have their fitnesse server running on the same drive or path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current directory (System.Environment.CurrentDirectory) will be the path in your FitNesee server -d parameter (e.g. java -jar \apps\fitnesse\fitnesse.jar -d path\to\my\fitnesse\wiki). 
From there you can look in FitNesseRoot\files.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Is there a tidy way to get this into a fitnesse variable or symbol.  I want to be able to pass a full path and file name as a parameter to a method under test.  i.e. from the table in the wiki page

Comment: You could write a class to generate a string and put it in a symbol. |with|new|myclass| |check|path|>>path| and then use the value elsewhere |with|myotherclass| |dosomething|<<path|  (Can't seem to do line breaks in SO comments!)

Comment: |with|new|myclass|<br>|check|path|>>path|<br><br>|with|myotherclass|<br>|dosomething|<<path|